# How to generate different title in other page other than the title in the title page with no author and no date?

Tags: titles, author, date, titling, customize

I am using overleaf.
This is my code in main.tex file-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,hyperref,ulem,physics,enumitem,mathtools,titling}
\title{\LARGE{\textbf{The Solow Model}}}
\author{XYZ}
\date{}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{Introduction}
\input{Balanced Growth Path}
\input{Solving for k, y and c}
\include{Transitional Dynamics}

\end{document}`
```

In Transitional Dymanics.tex file, I would like to make a title 'Transitional Dynamics' with no author or dates on that page along with a suitable space between the title and a new paragraph after the title. What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like?

```
\begin{center}
  \LARGE{\textbf{The Solow Model}}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks a ton!